# Connecting 2 arduino on same ground

Tags: power

I'm working project which consist of 2 arduino running a 2 different sketch, However, can i make these 2 ic to run on same power +ve and same ground?

Comment: Yes, I think you can connect both gnd and both 5v pins. Which arduino board is it? The voltage regulator might get damaged when a strong 5v is suddenly applied to the 5v pin. When using a power supply for one board, it might be safer to connect both Vin and both gnd. Always connect the grounds (gnd pins) when more than one arduino board is used in the same project.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Just be sure, that you connect both Arduinos in parallel to the power source (both power inputs together to the power output of the source and both grounds together to the ground of the source), so that the current for the second Arduino won't flow through the first Arduino. Also use a power source, that is capable oft providing enough current for your needs.